# How to put two floating-like Slivers inside a CustomScrollView with SliverAppBar-like behavior?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say we have the following, simple `CustomScrollView`:

- A `SliverAppBar`
- Widget 1
- Widget 2
- Widget 3

The previous example must be able to meet the following requirements:

1. The `SliverAppBar` must have `floating: true`, so it appears when we scroll up again. Easy enough;
2. Widget 1 and Widget 2 *should behave something like the* `SliverAppBar`. Let me elaborate this:

   1. These two widgets aren't an `AppBar`, which means that no drawer should be painted on them, no insets or anything else should be reserved. They're plain widgets, I want to use my own implementations there;
   2. When I scroll down, I expect those two widget to just scroll and *disappear*... Again, easy enough;
   3. *When I scroll up again*, though, these two widgets should appear one after the other on the screen like so: SliverAppBar -> Widget 1 -> Widget 2, *without needing to scroll to the top*, i.e. behave just like the `SliverAppBar` with the `floating:true` option, **but** they must respect the aforementioned scroll order.
3. Widget 1 and Widget 2 *are hideable*: see example below;
4. Widget 3 is just the actual content, and behaves like a normal scrollable widget.

Here's the code of what I have right now. I tried to implement Widget 1 and Widget 2 with different approaches:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      var showGreen = false;
      var showRed = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            drawer: const Drawer(),
            body: Center(
              child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverAppBar(
                    title: const Text('My app bar'),
                    floating: true,
                    actions: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.grade_outlined),
                        tooltip: 'Add',
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            showGreen = !showGreen;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.grade),
                        tooltip: 'Remove',
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            showRed = !showRed;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  if (showGreen)
                    SliverAppBar(
                      toolbarHeight:
                          200, // I don't want hard-coded values in here!!
                      leadingWidth: 0,
                      titleSpacing: 0,
                      floating: true,
                      title: Container(
                        height: 200, // I don't want hard-coded values in here!!
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: const Placeholder(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  SliverPersistentHeader(
                    floating: true,
                    delegate: MyDelegate(showRed),
                  ),
                  SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      height: 2500,
                      child: const Placeholder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
      final bool showContents;
      const MyDelegate(this.showContents) : super();
    
      @override
      Widget build(
          BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
        return showContents
            ? Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: const Text(
                  "my contents",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
                ),
              )
            : const SizedBox.shrink();
      }
    
      @override
      // But this is not what I want! I want the maxExtent to be as much as the build() method needs!
      // I DO NOT want to hard code heights here!
      double get maxExtent => 200;
    
      @override
      // For some reason... the content isn't disappearing right away and instead I get an overflow error?
      double get minExtent => 0;
    
      @override
      bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Here's what I tried so far, with no luck:

- I tried to implement Widget 1 and Widget 2 as two SliverAppBars, but:

  - Removing the Drawer is hacky (see example: you have to force the title to expand): is it actually there and just not shown, or did the framework remove that button entirely?
  - I want to leave these Widgets' height unbounded (no, I don't want anything fixed, I need their height to fit the content in a `Flexible` way); inserting anything besides a Placeholder breaks the AppBar as I'm not able to tell how much is needed in my contents beforehand!
  - This still feels like a hacky solution. I *don't want to have three* `SliverAppBars` *semantically speaking* (!)
  - This seems to be the "as-close-as-I-can-get" behavior, tho
- I tried `SliverLists`, `SliverGrids`... the behavior is impossible to reproduce with the "out-of-the-box" Widgets;
- I tried using a `SliverPersistentHeader` and its `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`, but I had no luck. I can't seem to understand how to consistently reproduce what I want with the maxExtent and minExtent parameters: I couldn't care less for *fixed* values (and as you see in the example, it just won't work well). Also, the `floating` behavior is just not there.

I am so lost with this one. Is anyone able to answer this?

Comment: What did you do in the end? I want the same. I think it will have to be done with SliverAppBar and a complex widget for the title, but it has some weird limitations with dynamic heights.